# How can I temporarily store data in a resilient way that is non-recoverable after deletion?

Tags: .net, security, key-value-store

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to store sensitive data for the lifetime of an asynchronous server side process.

Due to the sensitivity of the data, after the process is complete the data will be deleted and there should be no way to recover it.

Additionally, the storage of the data needs to be resilient to failure and secure during any internal network communication to or from the storage.

**My question**

Is there any software package out there that does most or preferably all of the following?:

- Provides this kind of ephemeral storage
- Supports secure server side communication (HTTPS)
- Supports resiliency (via clustering or some other means)
- Has a currently supported .NET client

***What are you trying to protect against?***

We want to be able to say that we have no way to recover the data either from backups, the file system, or even forensically retrieving it from disk.

***What have you looked at using?***

We've looked at a number of in memory Key-Value storage options such as Redis and ETCD, but they are built with speed in mind and I haven't found one that meets our requirements (Redis doesn't support HTTPS and ETCD has to write to disk)

We also looked briefly at using a Sql Server Memory Optimized Table - but the only way not to make it write to disk removes its resiliency.

Comment: If you are searching for a software package, the question can be off-topic here. It is on-topic at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: While I phrased my question as a request for a software package, I'm also interested in other possible answers along the lines of "you're doing it wrong" (if I am) or alternative architectural suggestions, which I don't think I would get at Software Recommendations.